# React Material UI v5 styled with defaultProps

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components, react-props

When using multiple styled components, the top one overrides other default props.

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles'
import { Badge } from '@mui/material'


const Badge1 = styled(Badge)``

// this works if Badge1 is used directly: <Badge1 />
Badge1.defaultProps = {
    max: Infinity
}


const Badge2 = styled(Badge1)``    // styled Badge1

// this overrides defaultProps from Badge1. Prop max: Infinity does no apply here
Badge2.defaultProps = {
    variant: 'standard'
}
```

Badge2 has only variant: 'standard' default prop. It skips max: Infinity

How can I keep all the defaultProps from each level

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you style a component via multiple `styled` calls using Emotion, Emotion collapses the styling layers into a single wrapper component rather than adding an additional wrapper around the first wrapper. Emotion [retains the defaultProps from the previous wrapper](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/blob/%40emotion/styled%4011.8.1/packages/styled/src/base.js#L183), but you are then overwriting that when you set `Badge2.defaultProps`.

You can retain any previous `defaultProps` with the following syntax:

```
Badge2.defaultProps = {
    ...Badge2.defaultProps,
    variant: 'standard'
}
```

Below is an example demonstrating what happens with default props with each `styled` wrapping. The fix is demonstrated with `StyledAgainWithDefaultRetainExisting`.

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

function MyComponent({ className, ...defaults }) {
  return <div className={className}>Defaults: {JSON.stringify(defaults)}</div>;
}
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  orig: true
};

const StyledMyComponent = styled(MyComponent)`
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
`;
StyledMyComponent.defaultProps = {
  styled: true
};

const StyledAgainNoDefaultsAdded = styled(StyledMyComponent)`
  background-color: purple;
`;

const StyledAgainWithDefault = styled(StyledMyComponent)`
  background-color: green;
`;
StyledAgainWithDefault.defaultProps = {
  styledAgain: true
};

const StyledAgainWithDefaultRetainExisting = styled(StyledMyComponent)`
  background-color: brown;
`;
StyledAgainWithDefaultRetainExisting.defaultProps = {
  ...StyledAgainWithDefaultRetainExisting.defaultProps,
  styledAgainRetain: true
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent />
      <StyledMyComponent />
      <StyledAgainNoDefaultsAdded />
      <StyledAgainWithDefault />
      <StyledAgainWithDefaultRetainExisting />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit styled and defaultProps]

Comment: This way we have to spread defaultProps, propTypes and args every time when we use styled. There should be a better way. styled((props) => <Component {...props} />)`` works as well, but it does not look like the perfect answer neither.

Comment: The method described above works currently. But please note that defaultProps for functional components is deprecated. The recommended way looks like this (https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component#specifying-a-default-value-for-a-prop). Thus, to solve your problem, you would have to create a wrapper component that would apply default props through argument destructuring.